# SkyDrive WinRT API Login programmatically

Tags: windows-runtime, onedrive

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to login to SkyDrive without having to show the UI to login not even once. The reason we're trying to do this is because we need to run some integration tests, and we need to login for that, but we can't add UI to those.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if user has done single sign on i.e. device connected with live account then UI will not be shown. So you have to check whether single sign on is done or not.

Comment: The problem is that if the user hasn't then we DO need to show UI, but we can't. I need a way to login without ever showing UI.

Comment: how will one do login without login UI ???

Comment: @Xyroid That is my question. I'm not sure what your attitude was by asking that, but please try to stay constructive.

Comment: then explain me how one can login w/o any UI, is there default login ID & password ? explain me the scenario.

Comment: @Xyroid by somehow sending the user name password to the API through code, or by getting the credentials from the windows credentials manager maybe. Like I said, the scenario is that we need to run integration tests on the SkyDrive API, for which we need to login, but we can't have any UI in the integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think Live Connect API doesn't provide a way to login via code-behind or via custom login panel. If you have access token then you can use REST APIs to get data like `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=<Access-Token>` will returns JSON response of id, first name, last name, profile link etc.

[Possible ways sign in to Live](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826543.aspx)

[Creating a non-web-view-based sign-in screen for Microsoft SkyDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743243/creating-a-non-web-view-based-sign-in-screen-for-microsoft-skydrive)

[Using REST to Login user to Windows Live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740216/using-rest-to-login-user-to-windows-live)